# Percentage SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, expression

I have two text boxes in my SSRS report.

The Total Number is simply - `=COUNT(Fields!CommunicationId.Value)`
The First Call Resolutions = `=SUM(Fields!FirstCallResolution.Value)`

The FirstCallResolution simply has a 1 for when it is a first call resolution and a 0 when it is not.

What would the expression be to get this to show the % correctly in SSRS?

Thanks

[image]

Edit : format code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do calculations in your expressions. Try

`=(SUM(Fields!FirstCallResolution.Value) / COUNT(Fields!CommunicationId.Value)) * 100`

Comment: Be careful when doing this that you don't end up dividing by 0. I would write a divider function that handles the case when `COUNT(Fields!CommunicationId.Value) = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

If you looking for a precision and a percentage representation., you can also write the below expression in the text box where you want the result to be displayed.

```
=(SUM(Fields!FirstCallResolution.Value) / COUNT(Fields!CommunicationId.Value))
```

You can then do a custom formatting for this text box in the Text-Box properties.
**Right click on Text Box** --> **Text Box Properties** --> **Number**-->**Custom**, and enter **P1** or **P2** or **P3** and so on for number of decimal places after the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Round function in your expression. With this function `=ROUND(...,1)` you'll get one number after the decimal point. If you want two numbers after the decimal point then use 2 instead of 1, and so on.

```
=Round(((SUM(Fields!FirstCallResolution.Value) / COUNT(Fields!CommunicationId.Value)) * 100),1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `=FORMAT((SUM(Fields!FirstCallResolution.Value) / COUNT(Fields!CommunicationId.Value)),"P")`