# Percentage Calculation In SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

when i am calculating like given below in **SSRS 2008**

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!REMARKS.Value = "GOOD",1,0))/((SUM(IIF(Fields!REMARKS.Value = "GOOD",1,0))+ SUM(IIF(Fields!REMARKS.Value = "BAD",1,0))))*100

getting result like 34.9632565235


but i am trying to get result like 34.97%
```

Please share your expertise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
=FORMAT(
SUM(IIF(Fields!REMARKS.Value = "GOOD",1,0))/
((SUM(IIF(Fields!REMARKS.Value = "GOOD",1,0)) +
SUM(IIF(Fields!REMARKS.Value = "BAD",1,0)))),"P2")
```

Or you can use a custom string format:

```
=FORMAT(
    SUM(IIF(Fields!REMARKS.Value = "GOOD",1,0)) /
    ((SUM(IIF(Fields!REMARKS.Value = "GOOD",1,0)) +
    SUM(IIF(Fields!REMARKS.Value = "BAD",1,0)))*100)
,"0.00") & "%"
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @RohiniMathur, Try copying and pasting the same expression I posted.

Comment: @RohiniMathur, I've added another solution and updated the first expression which uses a "P2" string format.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `Round` function in your expression. With this function `=ROUND(..., 1)` you will have one number after the decimal point. If you want two numbers after the decimal point then enter 2, and so on. (So you need 2).

Also check the link : [Percentage SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38762523/percentage-ssrs)

Where the example is used :

```
=Round(((SUM(Fields!FirstCallResolution.Value) / COUNT(Fields!CommunicationId.Value)) * 100),1)
```